# Regexextract to get a text in the middle of string

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrays, regexextract, regexplace

[SAMPLE SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uO6mw6T9vK9mN8ZRtCJXX5UT8yV_rL-4_fD2TZbiDbk/edit#gid=1709673224)

I have data in a column in this format:

1   P01 - Product Name here - PAID IN FULL

2   P02 - Product2 Name here - PARTIALLY PAID 20

1   P03 - Product2 Name here

I've been trying to extract just the middle part, i.e. the code & product name, using regex. This bit **P03 - Product2 Name here** The dash between the code & name should be left as is.

I managed to remove the first bit, 1.... etc, but I can't seem to get rid of the last bit *- PAID IN FULL* etc. This last dash should also go.

Using Regexreplace

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A3, "^(\d)\s", "")))
```

> result: P01 - Product Name here - PAID IN FULL

Regexextract

```
=arrayformula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A3, "[^(\d)\s].*"))
```

> result: P01 - Product Name here - PAID IN FULL

```
=arrayformula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A3, "[^(\d)\s+].*[^-A-Z$]"))
```

> result: P01 - Product Name here - PAID IN

Extract & replace

```
=arrayformula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A4, "[^(\d)\s+].*[^-$]"))
```

result:

[image]

Same above formula edited a bit to remove ^ before - :

```
=arrayformula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A4, "[^(\d)\s+].***[-$]**"))
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a capturing group, we can match a pattern then choose which part of the pattern we want to return.

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A4,"^\d\s+(\w\d+\s+-\s+[A-z 0-9]+)"))
```

Notes:

1. I'm using `\s+` since I noticed that the spaces can be a variable length.
2. `^\d\s+` This is the beginning of the text. I have a feeling this won't change significantly.
3. `\w\d+` is the P01. If your product code can include many leading letters, change it to `\w+\d+`.
4. `\s+-\s+` is just the dash, including the spaces around.
5. `[A-z 0-9]+` is just a char set that includes all alphanumeric characters and spaces. Simply adjust this if your product names aren't included here. Dashes in product names will not work for this pattern.

Comment: Wow David. That worked. I swear I tried numerous combinations but none worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome, @Genny !